# Fullscreen Frame Borders in Java LWJGL

Tags: java, fullscreen, lwjgl

I want to make a game with Java and LWJGL. In many videogames you can see the black fields at the top and the bottom of the display, which is used to size the display in the resolution the game can work with.

I searched for this two days, but maybe I used wrong keywords.

So is there any possibility I can make this with LWJGL. Maybe a method I can use?